# Shifting and phase difference

Tags: dft, phase

Assume we have a series v[k] of length M=16. It's shifted to the right in a circular manner by k0=2 samples.

Which phase difference between the DFT spectrum of the original signal and that of the shifted version is to be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [phase shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem) will be a factor of $e^{j2\pi k_0 m/M}$, where $m$ is the DFT bin number